# Cant follow Android Studio guide (Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, r.java-file

I wanted to create a Navigation Drawer for my App but I can't access the drawables from android. http://puu.sh/lq3Ba/5f05fda724.png. Android Studio keep telling me that there is no R.drawable.ic_drawer. If I open R.java then there are integer which starts with abc_... and I can't access them either.

I already tried to delete R.java and rebuild the whole project.

So my question is how can I access to the android icons (use ic_drawer or other icons)?

Comment: which you want to use that deprecated class follow this you will get an idea http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Thats the guide i followed, but i cant use R.drawable.ic_drawer used in this guide and i dont know why i cant use it.